# How to place data inside the body of the component using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, my objective is to place the `display` content inside the body of the Editor component which is a child component to `SendForm` Component. i could place down but i couldn't able to place inside the editor component. (My Motive is to forward the `form details` if wanted through `sendForm component`).

Here is the code:

```
 const Details = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div> Name: {this.props.data.name}</div>;
          <div> Phone Number: {this.props.data.phoneNumber}</div>;
          <div> Email: {this.props.data.email}</div>;
          <div> Address: {this.props.data.address}</div>;
        </div>
      );
    };
    return (
      <Container>
        <Modal trigger={<Button>Show Content</Button>}>
          <Modal.Content>
            <Editor name="content" value={this.state.content} />
            <Details />
            <Button>Send</Button>
          </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
      </Container>
```

Here is the whole code: "https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-river-fmuyt"

Can anyone help me in this query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to have `Details` component inside 'Editor' component? Something like `<Editor><Details/></Editor`?

Comment: @Sandy - Yes, you're right

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 approaches.

1. Pass as props.

In return statement of `SendForm.js`.

```
<Editor name="content" value={this.state.content} />
  <Details data={this.state.data} />
</Editor>
```

Above seems quite straight forward approach. However not sure why you were not willing to do above. Maybe because you need to pass some additional attributes to `Details` component from `Editor` component. If so, see approach 2.

2. Every component's `props` has a property called `children`. This children represents all the content inside the component.

I can see you need to pass some addition props to your children. For that you will need to create clone of children with additional attributes.

**SendForm.js**

```
return (
  <Container>
    <Modal trigger={<Button>Show Content</Button>}>
      <Modal.Content>
        <Editor name="content" value={this.state.content}>
          <Details />
        </Editor>
        <Button>Send</Button>
      </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
  </Container>
);
```

**Editor.js**

```
const Editor = (props) => {
  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      details: props.value,
    })
  });
  return <React.Fragment>{childrenWithProps}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

**Details.js**

```
const Details = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div> Name: {props.details.name}</div>;
      <div> Phone Number: {props.details.phoneNumber}</div>;
      <div> Email: {props.details.email}</div>;
      <div> Address: {props.details.address}</div>;
    </div>
  );
};
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: In Editor.js, it is showing error that children is not defined, if i convert into funtional component (as i'm not aware of functional or stateless components)

Comment: Change it to props.children

Comment: It's not showing the details while i click on the button :(